# Resize an image with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, image-manipulation, imagemagick, paperclip

The Paperclip plugin for Rails has a resize option that keeps the image in proportion.
According to Ryan Bates' [Paperclip Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip), to make sure that option is on, you have to add a greater-than sign in the end of the size for the style you're looking to resize, as such:

```
:styles => { :small => "160x160>" }
```

I'm looking for Paperclip to resize my image to an exact size, even if that means it being out of proportion, so I figured that removing the greater-than sign would do the trick, as such:

```
:styles => { :small => "160x160" }
```

Well, turns out nothing happens. So the greater-than sign is redundant in the first place.
I'm still left with the following question, though:

How would I force the image into a set size, ignoring proportions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can use "160x160#" which will scale and crop to exactly that size, which is unique to paperclip.  Otherwise you can use any of the ImageMagick geometry strings, detailed here:

[ImageMagick Geometry](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry)

But I'll quote the one you're interested in:

```
"160x160!"
```

> Width and height emphatically given,
>   original aspect ratio ignored.

Comment: Boy, it would be nice if [the Paperclip documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#post-processing) actually mentioned this.

Comment: Yes, but then what would we use Stack Overflow for?