# Paperclip resize and crop to rectangle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, paperclip

So I am expecting a series of photos of different sizes and aspect ratios. I want to be able to shrink/stretch the photo to fit as much as it can in a 200x100 rectangle and then crop the rest that does not fit. I want the crop to happen around the center as well. Is this possible? I am so confused with the imagemagick documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a direct answer for you, but WordPress has some excellent Javascript image edit/crop tools in the Post-edit admin WYSIWYG editor that you might take a look at.

Answer (score 19):

Paperclip's `#` option will do exactly what you want: fit the image maximally within the specified dimensions then crop the excess with gravity at the center.

Example:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
                  :styles => {
                    :original => "200x100#"
                  }
```

**Note:** If you want to keep the original intact and generate an additional cropped thumb, just change the `:original` key to something else, like `:thumb`.

Reference: http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/ClassMethods

Answer (score 1):

are any of these usefull?

[Resize an image with Paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389723/resize-an-image-with-paperclip-rails)

[Simple cropping with Paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017509/simple-cropping-with-paperclip)

http://mfischer.com/wordpress/2009/02/02/multiple-image-upload-and-crop-with-rails/comment-page-1/